# Smoothly transition from midway through CSS animation to start (or end)

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a box that spins on click:

```
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.box.spin{
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}
```

When you click it a second time, I'd like it to either unspin, or complete its spin to come to a halt. It seems that instead it snaps immediately back to its starting position:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/OaoPKm?editors=0100

Is there a way of achieving this without replacing the animation with a transition?

Answer (score 2):

What about use `animation-play-state` property ?

```
.box{
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear; // add this here
  animation-play-state: paused; // pause animation by default
}

.box.spin{
  animation-play-state: running; // play animation
}
```

https://codepen.io/frantisekvrab/pen/YROXaZ

If you like to complete the spin, I assume you have to use some more JS or CSS transition.

Answer (score 0):

By "unspin" do you mean to have it spin in the other direction? If so, you can do something like this:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  let box = document.querySelector('.box');
  box.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('spin')
    this.classList.toggle('spin-reverse')
  });
}
```

```css
@keyframes spin{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

html, body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:red;
  transition: all 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  user-select: none;
}

.box.spin{
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}

.box.spin-reverse {
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="box spin" id="box">
  Click to toggle animation
</div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/WYgQQW) :)